# How to understand what part of my Java loop outputs the asterisk?

Tags: java, loops, methods

Can anyone please tell me which part outputs the number in front of the `*` signs? Is it the methods or the output?

```
import java.util.*;

public class PrintTriangle3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter number");
        int number = sc.nextInt();
        int i = 1;
        while(i <= number) {
            System.out.println(printLine(number));
            number--;
        }
        i++;
    }

    public static int printLine(int number) {
        for(int j = 1; j <= number; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try auto-formatting your code. Its behavior will be far more clear then.

Comment: `System.out.println(printLine(number));`?

Comment: just print the * sign.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the number that return from the method. You can change it like this so you won't print the return value of the method,

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("enter number");

        int number = sc.nextInt();

        int i = 1;
        while (i <= number) {
            printLine(number);
            System.out.println();
            number--;
        }
        i++;

    }

    public static int printLine(int number) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= number; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");

        }
        return number;
    }
}
```

This was the part where you have print the number that returned by the method,

```
System.out.println(printLine(number));
```

Also you can change the type of that method to void since you don't need to return that value